# A stationary process defined by a really weird stochastic integral.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

A post here: [Distribution of integral with respect to Brownian motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328495/distribution-of-integral-with-respect-to-brownian-motion) described a really weird stationary process.

Let us make it simpler, by only considering for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $$X_{n}:=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(nx)Z(dx),$$ where the orthogonal stochastic measure $Z(dx)$ as described in the post has the property $$\mathbb{E}Z=0\ \text{and}\ Var(Z(dx))=\rho(dx)=dx,$$ where $\rho$ is the structure measure of $Z$, which coincides with the spectral measure of $X_{n}$.

Then, following the post, I tried to compute the variance function, covariance function, mean, etc.

For the mean, recall that $\mathbb{E}[Z(d\lambda)]=0$, so we have $$\mathbb{E}X_{n}=\mathbb{E}\Big(\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(n\lambda)Z(d\lambda)\Big)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(n\lambda)\mathbb{E}[Z(d\lambda)]=0.$$

---

However, the covariance function is really weird. Below is my computation:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(X_{n}\overline{X_{n+k}})&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(n\lambda_{1})\cos((n+k)\lambda_{2})\mathbb{E}[Z(d\lambda_{1})\overline{Z(d\lambda_{2})}]\\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(n\lambda)\cos[(n+k)\lambda]d\lambda\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\sin[2\pi(k+2n)]}{k+2n}+\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\sin(2\pi k)}{k}.
\end{align*}

The final answer can be easily computed using WolframAlpha.

So, the covariance function depends not only on $k$ but also on $n$ ???? Then the process cannot be stationary.. right?

---

To verify my computation, I changed a way to compute it by using Herglotz Theorem: $$c(n)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{in\lambda}\rho(d\lambda),$$ but $\rho(d\lambda)=d\lambda$, so that for $n>0$, $$c(n)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{in\lambda}d\lambda=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(n\lambda)d\lambda+i\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(n\lambda)d\lambda=\dfrac{\sin(2\pi n)}{n}+i\dfrac{2\sin^{2}(\pi n)}{n}.$$

This times, $c(n)$ depends on $n$ but we create some complex number...Also, you can see that the case has to be discussed differently if $n=0$, or $n<0$.

---

So the process is complex-valued?? What is the exactly this process? I am really confused....

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, the covariance function depends not only on k but also on n ???? Then the process cannot be stationary.. right?

Note that $\sin 2\pi m = 0$ for integer $m$, so
$$
\mathbb{E}(X_{n}\overline{X_{n+k}}) = 0, k\neq 0,
$$
and
$$
\mathbb{E}(|X_{n}|^2) = \pi.
$$
Therefore, the process is (wide-sense) stationary.

> So the process is complex-valued?

The answer depends on whether your $Z$ is complex-valued or not (which is not completely clear from your question).

Comment: oh. By the way, is there any further description you could give for $X_{n}$? say, distribution, etc?

Comment: I'd like to describe $X_{n}$ as much as possible.

Comment: I agree with everything you said, but a weird thing is that $$\mathbb{E}|X_{0}|^{2}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\lambda=2\pi,$$ seems not consistent with our computation.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical, you are right, $X_0$ should be divided by $\sqrt{2}$. Concerning the distribution, it depends on that of $Z$. Say, if $Z$ is Gaussian, then $X$ is too.

Comment: Concerning the distribution, since we have $Z$ is Gaussian, then $X$ is also Gaussian, but each $X_{n}$ is uncorrelated and thus independent. But we know that for $n\neq 0$, we have $0$ mean and $\pi$ variance, so this is a Gaussian process with i.i.d components? but $X_{0}$ is differently distributed?

Comment: About $X_{0}$. The formula we computed gives the covariance function $c(s,t)=0$ if $s-t\neq 0$ and $c(s,t)=\pi$ if $s-t=0$. But then $c(s,t)\neq c(s-t)$, since $Cov(X_{0}, X_{0}=2\pi$... I am wondering this since my definition of wide-sense stationary needs me to have $c(s,t)=c(s-t)$. I understand it is enough to show $c(s,t)$ is a function of $s-t$. But the $X_{0}$ case really worries me.....

Comment: I am sorry. let me first accept your answer and reward the points. I cleared out my mind and saw why I had confusion. The computation for $k=0$ is $$\mathbb{E}(X_{n}\overline{X_{n}})=\mathbb{E}(|X_{n}|^{2})=Var(X_{n})=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^{2}(n\lambda)d\lambda=\dfrac{\sin(4\pi n)}{4n}+\pi=\pi,$$ but note that the denominator has $n$, so we also need to require $n\neq 0$. Thus, we actually have three cases. $k\neq 0$, $k=0,n=0$, and $k=0,n\neq 0$. But then the covariance function also depends on $s$ and $t$, not only on $s-t$.

Comment: The situation with $X_0$ is this: under the link, there is $e^{in\lambda}$, and $B$ is complex-valued, so the imaginary part also contributes to the variance, which gives the same variance for $X_0$ (where $\sin = 0$). Here, you have only $\cos$, so one needs to take account of this.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. Thank you so much!